# how can i obtain exactly 25 reputation points on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, reputation

due to an inside-joke with friends, it would be amusing for us if i could manage to have exactly 9001 reputation points, which is now 25 points away. is there some way to obtain exactly 25 points?

<sub><sub><sub>(also got the message "At least one of these tags is required - 'bug feature-request discussion support'.", i'm not sure if i should have chosen "support" or "discussion")</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Technically, 9002 is “over nine thousaaaaaaand!!!” too. The joke will still work.

Comment: Has you motivation anything to do with Hearthstone?

Comment: This is so mid-2000s.

Comment: Is this not covered by a combination of https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation and simple math?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer a question that gets 1 upvote and 1 accept. The challenge is getting your answer accepted while it has exactly 1 upvote, no more, no less; or getting your answer upvoted once after it's been accepted, but depending on your tags it shouldn't be too difficult. It's all a matter of timing, I guess.

If you're considering collaborating with your friends on this, errr, as long as your friend has a legitimate question for you to answer and you have a good answer to share I guess I'm not going to complain, since I assume this will be a one-off thing...

Comment: it is a one-off thing, i just need it long enough to take a screenshot :) and thanks

Comment: @hanshenrik in that case you can just change it in the browser using dev tools

Comment: @hanshenrik: Good luck. I still remember the one time some random downvoted me and made my rep a palindromic number. I'll never find out if it was intentional...

Comment: @PeterJ that would be cheating =/

Answer (score 18):

Get plenty of rep and then downvote bad answers (-1) till you get down to number you like. You can start some bounties if you gain too much rep by mistake. Soo much easier than trying to get exact number of points.